# Query 2 tables from 2 machines and group results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that gives the right information back but I cannot figure out how to get distinct days and sum the count.  below is my query and the results shows what I get back, and what I would like to have come back.  I thought the union would join them and give my back the results that I wanted.  I have search for quite some time and have not located any help on this topic.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT COUNT(log_datetime) AS icount, CONVERT(varchar, log_datetime, 101) AS logdate
from openrowset('sqloledb', 'ServerName1';'UserID';'Password',
          'select * from DatabaseName..TableName where field1 > 899')
group by convert(varchar, log_datetime, 101)
union
SELECT COUNT(log_datetime) AS icount, CONVERT(varchar, log_datetime, 101) AS logdate
from openrowset('sqloledb', 'ServerName2';'UserID';'Password',
    'select * from DatabaseName..TableName where field1 > 899')
group by convert(varchar, log_datetime, 101)
order by logdate
```

```
Results
235     01/10/2013
312     01/10/2013
3091    01/11/2013
3197    01/11/2013
3339    01/12/2013
3536    01/12/2013
```

```
Wanted Results
547      01/10/2013
6288     01/11/2013
6875     01/12/2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT SUM(icount) AS icount, logdate FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(log_datetime) AS icount, CONVERT(varchar, log_datetime, 101) AS logdate
    FROM openrowset('sqloledb', 'ServerName1';'UserID';'Password',
              'select * from DatabaseName..TableName where field1 > 899')
    GROUP BY convert(varchar, log_datetime, 101)
        UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(log_datetime) AS icount, CONVERT(varchar, log_datetime, 101) AS logdate
    FROM openrowset('sqloledb', 'ServerName2';'UserID';'Password',
        'select * from DatabaseName..TableName where field1 > 899')
    GROUP BY convert(varchar, log_datetime, 101)
) AS tbl
GROUP BY logdate
ORDER BY logdate
```

And here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c142/3)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(1) icount, AA.logdate FROM
(
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, log_datetime, 101) AS logdate
from openrowset('sqloledb', 'ServerName1';'UserID';'Password',
          'select * from DatabaseName..TableName where field1 > 899')
union all
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, log_datetime, 101) AS logdate
from openrowset('sqloledb', 'ServerName2';'UserID';'Password',
    'select * from DatabaseName..TableName where field1 > 899')
) AA
group by AA.logdate order by AA.logdate
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe peterm's answer is correct, just wanted to add a note as to why.

With SQL, you have to think in sets.  You are creating two unique sets of data, and, using UNION, combining them.  However, your GROUP BY statements are within each set, not the combination.  Hence, the multiple row results.  By wrapping everything with another SELECT statement, you are querying the combined set, and are now able to group and aggregate.